# Can Netty's HAProxyMessageDecoder allow connections without HA Proxy data?

Tags: netty

My use case is that my Netty server is sitting behind a TCP proxy. The TCP proxy may or may not add info on the original client's connection using https://www.haproxy.org/download/1.8/doc/proxy-protocol.txt

It looks like the `netty-codec-haproxy` is good for this, however if a normal connection comes in that doesn't have the HA Proxy protocol at the beginning then `HAProxyMessageDecoder` fails and closes the connection. (I note in this case the class guesses the the HA Proxy Protocol v1 is used.)

Is there a way to get a `HAProxyMessage` for connections that have proxy data prepended to their connection, and for it to not do anything if there is no data prepended so I can continue processing the connection without that extra data available?

Comment: Note that your idea has severe security issues. What if the client sends a fake hproxy header of the connection, and you think hproxy header you receive is one hproxy injected. You want the server admin to configure if it should expect a header on that port

Comment: Yes, this can be a real issue for any type of forwarded data. But if you have the situation where the traffic goes `client -> router -> microservice` and the router ignores any proxy info given from the client, and the client can't connect to the microservice directly, then it doesn't matter what the client says. So I want it to be optional for the microservice, so that I can introduce the proxy protocol in a non-breaking way (allow microservice to optionally receive them; then turn on proxy procotol on the router separately).